# Rascal: resolve ambiguity with comment

Tags: comments, rascal, ambiguity

Consider the following grammar:

```
module Tst
  
lexical Id  = [a-z][a-z0-9]* !>> [a-z0-9];

layout Layout = WhitespaceAndComment* !>> [\ \t\n\r];
 
lexical WhitespaceAndComment 
   = [\ \t\n\r]
     | @category="Comment" ^ "*" ![\n]* $
     ;
 
start syntax TstStart = Id*;
```

then

```
start[TstStart] t = parse(#start[TstStart], "*bla\nABC");
```

gives an ambiguity, probably because the comment can be placed before or after the empty list of strings.
So, I have 2 questions:

1. How can I use `diagnose()` to get a diagnosis? I have tried `diagnose(t)` and `diagnose(parse(#start[TstStart], "*bla\nABC"))`, without success.
2. What is the ambiguity and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it has been a while ago. The comment definition contains a flaw, it has  to be corrected as follows:

```
@category="Comment" ^ "*" ![\n]* $
```

This resolves the ambiguity, but I still would like to know how to use `diagnosis()`.

Answer (score 0):

- The ambiguity is caused by `![*]*` which can eat a `\n` or not, because the whitespace notion can also eat the `\n` or not.
- The diagnose function is notoriously bad at spotting issues with whitespace. That can be improved.
- The solution is to use `![*\n]*` and end the comment line with `"\n"`
- Another ambiguity will happen with actual `*` comments in the code, between `String*` and `Id*` the comments would go before or after the empty lists. To fix this: `layout Layout = WhitespaceAndComment* !>> [\ \t\n\r] !>> [*];` adding the follow restriction with the `[*]` will help.

Answer (score -1):

When I make the example slightly more complicated I get another ambiguity.

```
module Tst
  
lexical Id  = [a-z][a-z0-9]* !>> [a-z0-9];
lexical String = "\"" ![\"]*  "\"";

layout Layout = WhitespaceAndComment* !>> [\ \t\n\r];
 
lexical WhitespaceAndComment 
   = [\ \t\n\r]
     | @category="Comment" ^ "*" ![\n]* $
     ;
 
start syntax TstStart = String* Id*;
```

Then `"*bla\nABC"` gives an ambiguity again. Probably because the comment can be placed before, within and after the empty list of strings. How to resolve it?

Comment: better edit the original question @stevenklusener because this is now an "answer"